# expectEvent with string returning a non-string value

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I am using `expectEvent` from OpenZeppelin's [Test Helpers](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#expect-event), and when running a Truffle test to check the event, it's all fine for address and integer fields, but have an issue for  **string** type.

Given a smart contract with this event and function:

```
  event WithdrawERC20Token(
     string indexed tokenSymbol,
     address to,
     uint256 amount
  );

  function withdrawERC20(
     string calldata tokenSymbol,
     address to,
     uint256 amount
  ) external {
     //...
     emit WithdrawERC20Token(tokenSymbol, to, amount);
  }
```

And this test:

```
const { expectEvent } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

// ...

it('should withdraw ERC20 tokens', async () => {
   //
    const txReceipt = await swapManagerContract.withdrawERC20Token(
        'UNI', 
        investor1, 
        50
    );
    expectEvent(txReceipt, 'WithdrawERC20Token', { 
        tokenSymbol: 'UNI',
        to: investor1,
        amount: new BN(50),
    });
}
```

I get this output error:

> ```
>   expected event argument 'tokenSymbol' to have value UNI but got 0xfba01d52a7cd84480d0573725899486a0b5e55c20ff45d6628874349375d1650
>   + expected - actual
>
>   -0xfba01d52a7cd84480d0573725899486a0b5e55c20ff45d6628874349375d1650
>   +UNI
> ```

It looks like the `tokenSymbol` is stored in kind of hexa format in the EVM. I have tried to apply several conversions to the string 'UNI' (*fromAscii*, *asciiToHex*, etc) but nothing gets this string into '0xfba01d52a7cd84480d0573725899486a0b5e55c20ff45d6628874349375d1650'.

Any clue on how to check the string from the event with `expectEvent` function?

Comment: as your `tokenSymbol` is an unbounded indexed field, it doesn't goes directly into the data section of the receipt, it goes encoded according this specification https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/abi-spec.html?highlight=indexed#encoding-of-indexed-event-parameters

Comment: I see. The indexed string is hashed using keccak256, so this can be used to compare the original value in the tests. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the string is an unbounded indexed field and therefore stored using `keccak256`. This can be used the other way around to compare the value in the tests.

In other words, this change worked for me:

```
expectEvent(txReceipt, 'WithdrawERC20Token', { 
    tokenSymbol: web3.utils.keccak256('UNI'),
    to: investor1,
    amount: new BN(50),
});
```